# Is this a well known NP-complete problem?

Tags: np, computational-complexity, graph-theory

I came across this problem recently and I wanted to know whether it was a well known NP-complete problem. I checked the library but could not find anything that matched exactly.

Given a directed weighted graph G. Find the minimal weight path of length 'n' in the graph.
Which is without setting any specific start node or end node.

This is not my field, so you will pardon me if the solution is trivial.

Comment: All paths of length n are equally short, aren't they? They all have length n...

Comment: Welcome to MO! (Just a very minor nitpick: Using 'shortest' and 'length' with two different meanings in the same sentence tends to be confusing.)

Comment: Yes it refers to the sum of the weights of the edges on the path of length 'n'.
Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Is your path allowed to visit the same node more than once?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous as stated.  By "shortest" do you mean fewest edges or least weight?  By length n, do you mean a path with n edges or a path of weight n?  Also, to be considered as a question that possibly lies in NP, it needs to be stated as a decision problem (e.g. "does G contain a path of length n with weight < w?").

Comment: A path can visit the same node more than once yes.
By shortest I meant least weight. By length I meant the number of edges. I think Francois was kind enough to correct the question that now should be clearer.

Andrew you are absolutely right that it should be stated as a decision problem. Actually, knowing whether the decision problem lies in NP solve my problem.


Comment: The fact that you don't specify the start and end node is irrelevant since if you can do it in polynomial time with a specific pair of nodes then you can do it in polynomial time by checking all $n^2$ pairs of nodes.

Comment: If all the edges have the same length, which you seem to be saying, just take the edge of minimum weight in the whole graph and go along it back and forth n times.

Comment: @Mio - the graph is directed. 

Comment: Ooops, missed that, now it makes sense. Thanks Sam.

Comment: @Andrew V. Sutherland: the OP asked whether the problem was NP-complete, not whether it was in NP.

Comment: @TonyK: I was merely responding to Daniele's comment above "knowing whether the decision problem lies in NP solves my problem".  In any case, I think the question is now more or less clear and I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 16):

The shortest (in terms of weight) path, constrained to have exactly n (or at most n) edges, can be found in polynomial time. For instance, given your graph $G=(V,E)$ make an expanded graph $H$ that has as its vertices the pairs $(v,i)$ where $v\in G$ and $0\le i\le n-1$. Draw an edge in $H$ from $(v,i)$ to $(w,i+1)$ whenever $G$ has an edge from $v$ to $w$, with the same weight. Then the shortest $n$-edge path in $G$ from $v$ to $w$ is the same as the shortest path in $H$ from $(v,0)$ to $(w,n)$. To look for paths in $G$ that are at most $n$ edges long, add to $H$ edges of weight zero from $(v,i)$ to $(v,i+1)$.

However, these paths allow repeated vertices and edges. If repetitions are disallowed, and $G$ has $n+1$ vertices, then the shortest length-$n$ path is just a Traveling salesman path, so of course it's NP-complete.

Comment: That doesn't quite work if you regard non-edges as having weight zero, but even if you do have that convention you can make them into edges with very large weight instead and then the argument works again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, how do you find the minimal weight path of length $n$ in $H$?
Hasn't the same problem just shifted to $H$?


Comment: You just find the shortest path from (v,0) to (w,n-1).

Comment: Yes, but this way you are setting $v$ and $w$. While the problem is to find any path of length $n$, without choosing any $v$ or $w$.

Comment: As gowers already mentioned, "the fact that you don't specify the start and end node is irrelevant." In any case, you can do Dijkstra using all nodes $(\bullet,0)$ as sources and all nodes $(\bullet,n-1)$ as targets

Comment: Or perhaps I should say 'Dijkstra-ish', because the special structure of *H* lets you get away with a much simpler algo: Just handle the nodes $(\bullet,k)$ in order of increasing *k*. (No need for a priority queue.)

Comment: This is polynomial in the size of the graph and n.  Can you make it polynomial in the size of the graph and log n?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it were possible to reduce the dependence on n to logarithmic, at some expense in increasing the dependence on the size of the graph. But why would you care? That would only make an improvement when n is much larger than the size of the graph. Do you really care about paths that long?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of finding the longest path in a graph is NP-complete. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem.) It follows that the problem of determining whether there exists a path of length $k$ is NP-hard (since otherwise you could check all lengths $k$). But then give a huge weight to all non-edges, and your problem is seen to be NP-hard too.

Comment: Danielle said in a comment that paths are really walks (repeated vertices are allowed).

Comment: AH -- that changes things ...

Answer (score -4):

This is not even in NP! The input is n, which is of length log(n). But a certificate is of length n, which is exponential compared to log(n). So you can't verify a solution in polynomial time and so it's not in NP.

Comment: *G* is part of the input.

Comment: We can make n so big that the size of the graph is insignificant.